# Call a PHP function inside of a while loop

Tags: php, function, loops, while-loop

I have a function which gets a particular set of users from a table where a particular `WHERE` condition is meet.

I need to send each of them a message.

So, I used another function to send the message. And called that function inside he following while loop

```
while($user= mysqli_fetch_assoc($users_set)){
   send_message($user['email']);
}
```

**So, the problem is, the function is called only just one time. (Only with the last value of the loop)**

How to fix this problem and make the function called with each value of the loop...

This is the full code...

```
$query = "SELECT * ";
$query .= "FROM user ";
$query .= "WHERE confirmed = 0";

$user_set = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query);
confirm_query($user_set);

while($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_set)){
   send_message($user['email']);
}
```

Here is the send message function....

```
function send_message($email){
global $db_conx;

$invitee_user = get_user_by_email($email);

$query5 = "INSERT INTO notification(";
$query5 .= "description, user_id";
$query5 .= ") VALUES(";
$query5 .= "'You have been confirmed'";
$query5 .= ", {$invitee_user['id']}";
$query5 .= ")";

$result5 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $query5);

if($result5){
    //$_SESSION["message"] = "Notification sent". \mysqli_error($db_conx);
    return "OK";
}else{
    //$_SESSION["message"] = "Failed to send notification". mysqli_error($db_conx);
}
```

}

Here is the code for `confirm_query()`

```
function confirm_query($result_set){
if(!$result_set){
   die("Fatal Error Occured : Database Query Failed <a href=\"error-report.php\">Report this error</a>"); 
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that there is more than one row returned?

Comment: On this one iteration, does $user have a valid value? According to the PHP docs, the function mysqli_fetch_assoc() does not even exist: http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=mysqli_fetch_assoc&lang=de&scope=404quickref

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it returns more than one row. I checked it with an echo

Comment: @TimoSta So, what are u suggesting ?  mysqli_fetch_assoc()  function worked for me in my other queries..

Comment: Yes, that function does actually exist, though it could be a bit tricky to search for: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: What does `confirm_query` do?

Comment: @HaukeP. it's just a custom function I wrote. It checks whether the query returns true

Comment: Can you post 'send_message' source ?

Comment: You should post code for `confirm_query()` and `send_message()`; It could be that something in these functions in either impacting the DB connection or causing execution to abort.

Comment: @MikeBrant I added confirm_query() and  send_message()

Comment: is it send_message or send_invitation?

Comment: Not a good idea to do expensive operation when locking the database up. Grab the rows and then send the email

Comment: I don't see `send_message()` code i your updated post.  You did post code for `send_invitation()` though.  Not sure how this is related.

Comment: @MikeBrant  sorry about the mistake. I added the two pieces of code

Comment: You are returning `Ok` but not handeling it anywhere when you called `send_message()`. Don't you thinks it's might be the problem.?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh yeah, I returned it just to check how many times it's been called. I just forgot to erase it whn I'm posting it here... Sorry about that. Sure it's not a part of the original code

Comment: @EdHeal Yeah, I know this is little bit tiring the database. Is there anyway I can call this function , the number of times is determined by another query. What do u suggest ?

Answer (score 5):

I would just boil this down to one query and get rid of all the looping stuff

```
INSERT INTO notification (description, user_id)
SELECT 'You have been confirmed', user_id
FROM user
WHERE confirmed = 0
```

Your current logic is really convoluted.

You query the user table to get the user email field, then pass that email as parameter to your function only to then turn around and (I presume) look up the user ID based on email (when you already had this information from your initial query), then you make insert.

This means that for every record you return from first query, you need to do 2 queries to insert to the notification table.  So if you had 100 results you would end up doing a total of at least 201 queries to complete the insertions.

Using my approach you make 1 query regardless of how many rows are affected.

One takeaway that you should get from this is that, anytime you see yourself trying to do some sort of nested querying, you should recognize this as an anti-pattern (a coding pattern that you do not want to typically use).  There is usually a better approach that can be taken if you rethink how you are writing your queries.

Comment: Wow.. Haven't thought of this much of tricky sql command.... Thanks.. I'll give it a try... :)

Comment: @TharinduLucky No problem. I did add update to my answer that you should look over.  The real takeaway for you is learning that this is an anti-pattern you should recognize and rethink your approach when you encounter it.

Comment: I tried your answer, sure it opened my eyes. But, I ended up having another problem. Here I want to insert to notification table more than one row. How many users found with confirm = 0, that will be the number of records to be added to the notification table. Because I need to include some details specific to user in the description field of notification table. So, where to go now ?

Comment: @TharinduLucky It depends on what that user-specific information is and what it is generated from (does it already exist in user table?).  Your example just showed a static string (`You have been confirmed`) being inserted, so my answer was based on that.

Comment: Yeah, when I was asking the question I was just focusing on calling the function in the loop. Sorry about that. Anyway, I managed to do what I wanted with a `foreach` loop. First I get user specific emails (according to the condition) and store them in a array. Then loop through  that array using a `foreach` and call the function inside it. However, this may not be the smartest way of doing this. What do you think anyway ?

Comment: @TharinduLucky I think you are using an anti-pattern and should strongly consider simplifying your means of querying as I have pointed out.  Your approach is going to lead to ever significantly worsening performance as the number of rows meeting the SELECT criteria increases.

Comment: Thanks, but, I can't find a better way of doing this. I mean, I have to insert a number of rows that depends on a returned result of another query. So, instead of a loop, is there another way to do this insert query multiple times ?